# Can we change the App Service Slot name to be included as prefix as opposed to the suffix

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, environment

So adding a slot name as dev, would create the url as appservice-dev.azuresites.net. How can we create dev-appservice.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: You could use custom domains for each slot with whatever naming scheme you like.

Answer (score 0):

CrashOverride, the other two posters are correct. We do not allow customers to edit the internal DNS name (.azurewebsites.net) of deployment slots.

I do also want to confirm that your best solution if needing custom DNS names for your slots would be to use a custom domain name (you'll need to add a SSL cert).

We encourage you to make a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) so the product group is made aware of this scenario.